# getJSON fails when i try to load user JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook

I have made a chrome extension for facebook, for private liking. What I want to do is, whenever someone posted a post, and a person clicked the private like button, which has been included by me. On click of this private like button, i want to get the JSON data of the poster who posted the post. For now i just tried to get JSON of my own profile, but It does not return anything. Below is the code  !

```js
var btn = "<button class=\"nadddim\" >Get JSON</button>";
var t = document.getElementsByClassName("_sg1 _3qd4");
t[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', btn);



document.getElementsByClassName('nadddim')[0].addEventListener('click',function(){

var fbjson;

$.getJSON( "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004774025067", function( data ) {
  fbjson = data;
});

console.log(fbjson);
});
```

Basically need the user id , from his post, for example John posted something, whenever I privately liked that post, I want to get the JSON of John to extract his id value ! Thats All I need

Comment: @adeneo understand the question and then mark it duplicate

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I understood the question, and marked it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the method `.done()` to get the return data since the getJSON call is asynchronous like this:

```
$.getJSON( "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004774025067" ).
        .done(function( data ) {
            fbjson = data;
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
        })
```

Also, you might want to check if there's any errors using `fail()` , see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/. To view the content of the error examine the [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (jQuery XMLHttpRequest) for instance like this:

```
        .fail(function(jqxhr){
            console.log( "error" );
            console.log(jqxhr.responseText);
         })
```